# Spaces in the name of substitutional variables

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle Sql, we need to use '&' indicate substitution variable.
If the variable name is comprised with multiple words and I want to spaces between them, what should I do ?
I can of course connect these words with "_" like "&aaa_bbb_ccc", but if I have to use space rather than "_" what should I do ?

Comment: [This blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables) indicate it's allowed by quoting the identifiers with double-quotes, e.g. `"This is my column name"`. Give it a try. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis You can quote the value but I cannot see where it says you can quote the identifier.

Comment: Please explain “I **have** to”. What forces or requires you to use spaces in variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have spaces in the variable *name*. But the name shouldn't matter to anyone running the code, it just needs to be meaningful to whoever is writing and maintaining it.

I suspect whoever is running the code is seeing the name when they are prompted for the value, e.g. as a very simple example, if the code is:

```
select '&abc_def' from dual;
```

then a user running it sees:

```
Enter value for abc_def:
```

which isn't very friendly, and I can imagine you wanting to have spaces instead of underscores in that prompt - so perhaps that is what you really mean.

SQL *Plus (and SQL Developer, and SQLcl) lets you create your own prompt for a substitution variable value [with the `ACCEPT` command`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm):

```
accept abc_def char prompt = 'Please give a value for Abc Def';

select '&abc_def' from dual;
```

Now the end user see:

```
Please give a value for Abc Def:
```

You probably want to `set verify off` if you aren't already,

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) about using substituion variables.

Comment: Thank you Alex ! This is exactly what I am asking for !